# Javascript | Error al asignar un título

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Error al asignar título al layer. Se pretende que junto al icono se pueda ver un título para saber a qué layer o menú corresponde (Hay 4 layer que cada uno dispone diferentes categorías). Pero muestra el símbolo o el icono, pero ningún título. De esta manera no podemos distinguir un layer de otro.

**Código:**

```
var layerControlElements = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
  'PLCs': plc
}).addTo(map);
layerControlElements.title = "Título del layer";
```

4 Layer (que no tienen título):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los divs de los iconos tienen la clase `leaflet-control-layers`, osea que se puede hacer:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-layers")[i].prepend(titulo)
```

donde `i` es cada `L.control.layers`. `titulo` puede ser otro elemento html con estilos. Ejemplo completo en [este jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mt1La7n/).